# FireQuery-like plugin for Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, plugins

Is there a plugin for Chrome that allows you to see jQuery events attached to DOM elements? In Firefox you can use Firebug with the FireQuery extension, but I can't find anything like it for Chrome.

Are there any other easy ways to see the attached events in the Chrome inspector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not necessarily for Chrome inspector, but I personally love the bookmarklet [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event). It displays a great overlay above the page, with icons showing what elements have events bound to them, and you can hover over the icons to show the event code.

A helpful tool for any browser.

Comment: Wonderful tool! Guess it's the closest we get to FireQuery. In some aspects it's even better!

Comment: i'm sorry, i gotta downvote this because this tool is nothing compared to firequery.

Comment: it's not exactly the same, but it shows you events attached to elements (which seems one of they key features in FireQuery), and works in multiple browsers and with any type of event (plain DOM, jQuery, YUI, etc.). I think it's a useful tip.

Comment: the tool mentioned in the below [comment by Leksat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463889/201514) is much better than this one.

Answer (score 8):

I found "jQuery Debugger": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi

It isn't so handy as FireQuery, but it does its job well.

Answer (score 1):

Found this nice extension named **jQquery Audit** that allows you to see jQuery delegated events, internal data, and more, as live DOM nodes, functions, and objects.

Chrome web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-audit/dhhnpbajdcgdmbbcoakfhmfgmemlncjg/

Project page: https://github.com/zertosh/jquery-audit

Comment: Nice, jQuery Debugger, mentioned in @Lekstat's answer, didn't work for me (using Chrome 33), and Visual Event seems to have problems on scrolling websites.  This one really works.